# DAX - SELECTEDCOLUMNS

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem. My DAX knowledge is still very novice. So, this is the situation:

FILTER(
CROSSJOIN(
SELECTCOLUMNS(VALUES('dfProducts'[category1]), "item", 'dfProducts'[category1]),
SELECTCOLUMNS(VALUES('dfProducts'[category1]), "item2", 'dfProducts'[category1])
),
[item] > [item2]
)

I would also like to filter category1 by Flag columns who is also in dfProducts.

Your help is very appreciated.

U.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
Basket analysis = 

FILTER(
CROSSJOIN(DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS(dfProducts,"item",dfProducts[category1],"flag", dfProducts[Flag])),
DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS(dfProducts,"item2", dfProducts[category1],"flag1",dfProducts[Flag]))),
[item]>[item2] &&
[flag]="1" &&
[flag1]="1"
)
```